# How to find the coordinates of an n-dimensional rectangular simplex

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, simplex

How to find the coordinates of an n-dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) ?
Is there a formula to find the rest of the coordinates by providing some of them? Or by providing the center and the length of each edge?
There's some explanation on a 3D case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn), but is not general for ndim.
Would be great to have a python function as the following:

```
def n_simplex_coordinates(center,edge_length,dim):
  # calculate the coordinates
  # note: the number of coordinates are always dim+1
  return c[0], c[1], ..., c[dim]
```

PS: [Tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) is a 3-dimensional rectangular simplex

Comment: What's a "rectangular" simplex?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: You will find an original solution there : (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn)

Comment: A much simpler solution is in (https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/simplex_coordinates/simplex_coordinates.html):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following reference gives a very simple method and an associated Python code :
(https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/simplex_coordinates/simplex_coordinates1.py).

Let me explain the simple idea expressed in this reference.

We want to get coordinates of $n+1$ points in $\mathbb{R^n}$ that are all at the same distance one to the other.

Take for the first $n$ points the unit points on the $n$ different axes, and a $(n+1)$st one on the orthogonal vector to the plane $x_1 \ +  \ x_2 \ +  \ \cdots \ +  \ x_n=1$, i.e.,

$$e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix} \ \ e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}  \ \ e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}  \ \ \cdots \ \ e_n=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
f=\begin{pmatrix}a\\a\\a\\\vdots\\a\end{pmatrix}$$

The distance between all the $e_k$s is the same, i.e., equal to $\sqrt{2}$.

Thus it suffices to express that the distance between $f$ and all the other $e_k$s is also equal to $\sqrt{2}$. Let us take for example $k=1$. As

$$f-e_1=\begin{pmatrix}a-1\\a\\a\\\vdots\\a\end{pmatrix},$$

we must have: $\|f-e_1\|^2=2$ giving $(a-1)^2+(n-1)a^2=2$ whence
$na^2-2a-1=0$. This quadratic equation has two roots. Let us take the positive one (the other would be convenient too), giving

$$a=\frac{1+\sqrt{n+1}}{n}$$

The center of gravity $G$ of this set of $(n+1)$ points is the point with all its coordinates equal to $\tfrac{a+1}{n+1}$.

It is now easy to bring this set of points by a convenient translation to have any desired center, to shrink or enlarge it to the convenient sidelength, to rotate it, etc.

Remark: The Wikipedia reference on the subject uses the fact that, from the center of gravity, one "sees" a side under an angle of $\cos^{-1}(-\tfrac{1}{n}).$

Comment: thank you! I found a python function in the library you posted above. It has a function for calculating the coordinates:
https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/simplex_coordinates/simplex_coordinates1.py would be great if you also add this to your answer so that I can accept it as the final answer.

Comment: OK I will do it.